# What is the usage of pruneWork () method and When to use the method in WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I studied in the pruneWork method in the Developer's guide but i could not able to understand What they are saying..?

Prunes all eligible finished work from the internal database. Eligible work must be finished (WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED, WorkInfo.State.FAILED, or WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED), with zero unfinished dependents.

Use this method with caution; by invoking it, you (and any modules and libraries in your codebase) will no longer be able to observe the WorkInfo of the pruned work. You do not normally need to call this method - WorkManager takes care to auto-prune its work after a sane period of time. This method also ignores the WorkRequest.Builder.keepResultsForAtLeast(long, TimeUnit) policy.

Answer (score 4):

**`pruneWork()`** is used to remove all piled up cancelled worker schedules, the method returns `Operation` which states the completion of removal.

In case you found yourself in an extremely bad situation where you actually need to remove old workers, you can make a call to [pruneWork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#pruneWork()).